AndroidNotificationCategory is ignored in flutter local push notification plugin in emulator
I'm creating a local push notification and showing it using this code
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      data.hashCode,
      "$from - ${data['title']}",
      data['body'],
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          channelDescription: channel.description,
          category: AndroidNotificationCategory.message,
          // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
          //      one that already exists in example app.
          // icon: 'food',
            channelShowBadge: true,
          number: 11
        ),
      ),
    );

in ios I'm able to see that each notification has a category - Transaction, Messages, Notification etc. All applications have the same category names for push notifications. I believe that AndroidNotificationCategory.message is the similar beast but it is not the case in my scenario. Changing of that value has beed perfectly ignored no matter what I set. The question - am I right about categories on android and why it is ignored on android emulator?
